# Ruby on Rails how to get every row of a specific column of table? Loop through rows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, ruby-watir

I have this table like in the image showed below:
I am using Ruby Watir to get every row of the first column.

https://dominiumestate.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Capture.jpg

I have tried this but I can't get every row of the table only the first one with

```
puts t.tr(:index => 2, class: ['spy1xx']).td(:index => 0).font(class: ['spy14']).text
```

`t = browser.table(:index => 1).tbody()`

```
 puts t.trs(:index => 2, class: ['spy1xx']).each do |s|
 puts s.td(:index => 0).font(class: ['spy14']).text
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to:

1. Get a collection of the table rows
2. Iterate through each row to get the specific cell text.

Try:

```
browser.trs(class: /spy1x/, onmouseover: true).map { |tr| tr.font(class: 'spy14').text }
```

Comment: I have tried still shows the error of:  #<Watir::Font: located: false; {:index=>1, :tag_name=>"table"} --> {:tag_name=>"tr"} --> {:class=>"spy14", :tag_name=>"font"}> to be located; Watir treated ["scope"] as a non-HTML compliant attribute, ensure that was intended (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException) ...... im trying to get all the proxies and ports of this page http://spys.one/proxies/

Comment: @Rajagopalan can u help me in this topic too ?

Comment: @AstritShuli, thanks for providing the actual page. Part of the problem is that the table you need is not the second one - `index: 1`. Updated the answer with a solution that finds the right rows without the table index.

Comment: Thank you for everything